# What does real function of a complex variable mean?

Tags: complex-analysis

What does these terms mean

i) Real function of a complex variable

ii) Real function of a real variable

iii) Complex function of a real variable

iv) Complex function of a complex variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is about domain and range of the function.

i) Real function of a complex variable  $f:C\to R$

ii) Real function of a real variable $f:R\to R$

iii) Complex function of a real variable $f:R\to C$

iv) Complex function of a complex variable $f:C\to C$

Answer (score 3):

Examples:

$f(x+iy)=x$ defines  a real  function of  a complex variable.

$f(x+iy)=x+iy$ defines  a complex   function of  a complex variable.

$f(x)=x+ix$ defines  a complex  function of  a real variable.

$f(x)=x$ defines  a real  function of  a real variable.

In all these I assume that $x$ and $y$ are real.

Comment: So a real function of a complex variable means that variable can be a complex number and the value of it will be always real ?

Comment: @AKADeath Exactly.